# Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized) in using nuget.config with private feed of nuget github packages

Tags: .net, dockerfile, continuous-integration, nuget, github-actions

I have a issue to use github action to build dockerfile and using nuget github package in nuget.config file when push that to github repository that showing me *Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).* what can i do to resolve this issue?

*dockerfile:*
[image]

*nuget.config*:
[image]

*github action*:
[image]

*github*:
[image]

**Thank you for helping me**

everytime i push to main brach this action is running and should be building the dockerfile successfully for me

Comment: You need to delete the image of your nuget config, it has your username/password in it

Answer (score 0):

try replace

```
working-directory: ./
```

with

```
working-directory: ${{env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE}}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I added your solution to the code but the issue still persists

Comment: @HariKrishna It might be the wrong answer, but it is an answer nonetheless, as such you might want to downvote, but it should not be deleted in the review queue.